# Bash one-liner for "if a file exists, read it into variable, else empty string"?

Tags: bash

I can write:

```
X=""
if [ -f foo.txt ]; then
  X=$(<foo.txt)
fi
```

but this is 4 lines. Is there a more compact way to express this logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do just `X=$(< foo.txt)`, `X` will be empty if the file doesn't exist, but you'll get an error message:

```
$ X=$(< foo.txt)
-bash: foo.txt: No such file or directory
```

If you want to suppress that (but also any other error message), you can redirect stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
{ X=$(< too.txt); } 2> /dev/null
```

`X` is in fact empty afterwards:

```
$ declare -p X
declare -- X="
```

Comment: A bit less efficient but shorter to write `x=$(cat file 2>&-)`.

Comment: Is X unset or empty in the failure case here?

Comment: @CharlesNicholson Empty.

Comment: Cool, thanks! (will "accept" after the 5-minute cool-off expires).  I notice you put a space after the < inside the $(<foo.txt) expression. Is that stylistic or functional?

Comment: @CharlesNicholson Purely stylistic. I like having blanks around my redirections, and the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) also has a blank there ;)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use this one lines using success/error after file existence check:

```
[[ -f foo.txt ]] && s=$(<foo.txt) || s=''
```

`s=$(<foo.txt)` will be executed if file exists otherwise `s=''` gets executed.